Adding Camera animation to MMD three.js renderer
I have tried over the last days to implement a working animated camera to my already running MMD / PMX environment.
However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.
The regular animations for model and stage props already work,
But the camera eludes me.
I currently call the camera in a simple manner:
async function LoadCamera(id) {
  const path = "./camera/" + id + ".vmd";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const loader = new THREE.MMDLoader();
    
    loader.loadAnimation(path, camera, (animation) => {
      if (!animation || !animation.animations || animation.animations.length === 0) {
        reject(new Error(`Invalid animation file: ${path}`));
        return;
      }
      
      const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(camera);
      const action = mixer.clipAction(animation.animations[0]);
      action.play();

      function animateCamera() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animateCamera);
        mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      
      animateCamera();
      resolve(true);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('Error loading animation:', error);
      reject(new Error(`Error loading animation file: ${path}`));
    });
  });
}

However this is seemingly not enough as the console log claims:
Error loading camera animation: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
Any help would be appreciated
I also have the current - disfunctional - code here, with "camerafail.js" being the current - faily attempt
Multiple attempts to add the camera were made.
They all fail at render.
VMD parse for normal (bone based) animation works fine.
